# changing custom colors of a material-UI component to adjust dark mode

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

hi I have a customised chip component for material-UI app where i am changing the background and border color of the chip by using the grey object

now when I am switching to dark mode via the global theme
palette: {
type: "dark"
}
those colors not changing. is there some way to change those custome colors based if we are in light or dark mode?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import grey from'@material-ui/core/colors/grey';
import {Chip} from "@material-ui/core";
import {withStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";


const MyChip = withStyles(theme =>({
    root: {
         backgroundColor:grey[100],
         borderStyle: "solid",
         borderWidth: "1px",
         borderColor: grey[300]
    },
}))(Chip);

const ChipComponent = ({...props}) => {
    return <MyChip {...props} />
}

export default ChipComponent;
```

Comment: What does "switching to dark mode via the theme" mean specifically? The reason I ask is that I'm wondering if you can do something like: `backgroundColor: theme.darkMode ? grey[800] : grey[100],`

Comment: @BenStephens, thanks for the clarification, in my app i have a custom theme  which is placed in a separate Theme.js file and is called from the app.js via the   
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}> 
in this global theme  i have  the ability to switch between dark and light modes via the palette

with palette:{
   type: "light",
}
  it can be set to  type: "dark",

Comment: @BenStephens
now when I am adding your suggestion to my custom chip component
backgroundColor: theme.darkMode ? grey[800] : grey[100]
it looks that it is not recognizing the darkMode (even if it is set un the Theme,js file since it applyes only the right argument grey[100]

Comment: What about something like: `backgroundColor: theme.palette.type === 'dark' ? grey[800] : grey[100]` ? Hopefully it's just a matter of finding the correct property in theme to tell whether you're in dark mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to the solution of @BenStephens (see in the comments of the original question)
the solution is to add theme.palette.type === 'dark' ? grey[800] : grey[100] to the background /border colors

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Chip} from "@material-ui/core";
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import {withStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import grey from'@material-ui/core/colors/grey';

const MyChip = withStyles(theme =>({
root: {
     backgroundColor:theme.palette.type=='dark'? grey["700"]:grey["100"],
     borderStyle: "solid",
     borderWidth: "1px",
     borderColor: theme.palette.grey[300]
},
}))(Chip);


const ChipComponent = ({...props}) => {
    return <MyChip {...props} />
}

export default ChipComponent;
```